# Add a class to expanded row using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, ag-grid

In my angular application I am attempting a workaround because the ag-Grid api getRowClass() is not working at intended.  All I need to do is add a css class to an expanded row and remove it when the row is collapsed.

The original method using ag-Grid api that does not work looks as follows:

```
setRowNode(params) {
    this.gridOptions.getRowStyle = (params) => {
        if(params.node.expanded) {
            return { background: 'red' };
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I would be able to selected the DOM and append a class to it.  I tried this with some JQuery and it worked, but for obvious reasons I do not want to have JQuery in this app.  I wrote something along these lines:

```
$('.ag-row[row="'+params.node.id+'"]',self.api.grid.gridPanel.eBodyContainer).addClass('ag-row-focus');
```

How would I fulfill this req using vanilla JS?

Comment: Look at `querySelectorAll()` and `classList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a custom directive, like this one :

```
//row-focus.directive.ts

import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appRowFocus]' // you can target classes, id etc.: '.grid-Holdings' for example
})
export class RowFocusDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.ag-row-focus') isFocused = false;

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen() {
    this.isFocused = !this.isFocused;
  }
}
```

Import this directive on your module, and then attach the directive to your elements :

```
// your-component.component.ts :

<div class="row" appRowFocus>
```

These elements will toggle the `ag-row-focus` on click. You can add different `@HostListener` for other events.

Comment: Ok I think I understand the thrust of this, but my html looks like this:  

`<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height:85vh" class="ag-material grid-Holdings"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
            [rowData]="rowData"
            [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight"
            headerHeight="46"
</ag-grid-angular>`
I do not have access to the DOM of that specific row. How would I add that directive to this grid?

Comment: You can target what you want on directive selector, like class, tag etc. ! Maybe try with `. grid-Holdings` or `ag-grid-angular`

Comment: so inside the selector I could target like so:  `@Directive({
  selector: '[.grid-Holdings]' 
})`

Comment: Yes, but without brackets : `.grid-Holdings`

Comment: Right, this works, but the class is added to the entire `<ag-grid-angular>`, and not the individual row that is expanded/collapsed...sadly there seems to be no way to target the specific row.  I appreciate all of your help with this...I  learned something and got close...